# populate a blank column with proportions

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have two existing columns and have created a new blank column. When I try the following my NewColumn is populated with 1's and 0's. I would like a decimal representation of the proportion. It appears as though SQL is rounding. Column1 and Column2 are numeric and I defined NewColumn as Numeric also.

update MyTable

set NewColumnd = ((Column1/Column2)*1.00)

where Column2 != 0

here are the incorrect results

Column1  Column2   NewColumn

5.00      7.16      1

6.59      6.59      1

0.00      6.97      0

0.00     35.89      0

3.00      9.69      0

Sorry Ive had to repost this, but my entries continue to show up in a strange format

Comment: The percentage result is a calculated value. You do not want to store calculated values.  Generate them on as needed basis on the fly.  Also if Column2 is ever zero you will have a problem.

Comment: I need the populated column in MyTable to use on some analysis. Im not a SQL person, but for this project I am forced to use SQL before I load it into SAS

Comment: You can calculate it in SAS as needed.  Storing a calculated value means that if Column1 changes, you also have to change NewColumn.  If this is a one-shot thing, put it in and be done with it. Done is good.  If this is something you are going to be doing multiple times or on a regular basis, I would advise writing up the code to handle the calculations on an as-needed and not stored basis.

Comment: this is a one time thing.

Comment: Numeric??? What is the precision and scale for these column?  Run this:  Select Name, Precision, Scale From sys.columns Where object_id = object_id('YourTableNameHere')

Answer (score 0):

Try the following SQL Query :

```
declare @table table(column1 decimal(18,2), column2 decimal(18,2))

insert into @table
select 5.00 ,7.16 
insert into @table
select 6.59 ,6.59
insert into @table
select 0.00, 6.97
insert into @table
select 0.00, 35.89

select * ,case when column1 != 0.00 then ((Column1/Column2)*1.00) else 0 end as  column3
from @table
```

I am creating a temporary table, and note my columns are decimal and have column1, and column2. Then I am creating a new column3 on the fly, with a calculation.

To insert data into the temprary table what you can do is the following :

```
insert into @table
select CAST(column1 as decimal(18,2),
        CAST(column2 as decimal(18,2) from [YourTable]
```

This does seem to be an overkill though, and ideally if your columns should be of type decimal, you change those directly. You should also consider querying directly the table, and casting from int, to decimal(18,2), and then calculating the column as you along.

Comment: still nothing except 1's and 0's

Comment: In that case your problem is the column1, and column2 are of type int. If you execute my SQL query, you should get all decimal values.

Comment: Stephen, I have 5.4 million rows of data. will i need to do insert select for all of those?

Comment: I updated my answer to show you. If you cannot change the physical table, then yes you are going to have to select into the temporary table the data you require.

Comment: i can change the column properties in the original table, but how

Comment: Good. So even better. You do not need to insert into the temporary table then. So change the columns to decimal, because you are trying to insert in column1, and column2 decimal values. Then when you calculate column3, you should get actual decimals.

Comment: I tried update MyTable
set Column1 = convert(decimal(18,2),Column1)
        ,column2= convert( decimal(18,2),Column2) 
from MyTable                                                            update MyTable
set NewColumn = (Column1/Column2) 
  where Column2 != 0                                            There is still only 1's and 0's

Comment: With update, I meant this : alter table MyTable alter column column1 decimal(18,2)
alter table MyTable alter column column2 decimal(18,2)